# Can air-powered diaphragm pumps pump out the effluent at a higher pressure than inputed?

Tags: pumps

I am working on an acid filtration system and I need to be able to pressurize the effluent from the diaphragm pump such that the acid can be forced through a filter. I am not quite sure if a diaphragm pump can pressurize the influent and also be able to adjust the pressure. Can they do this? Or is there another pump that I should look for?

Comment: I am confused by your wording, please clarify what is meant by "also be able to adjust the pressure". In general, a diaphragm pump is a constant volume pump that can raise the pressure of the fluid as it is discharged from the pump, as shown in it's pump curve. You can try to find a pump that outputs the needed pressure, or have equipment after the pump to adjust the fluid's pressure.

Comment: Okay, well that pretty much answers my question. I was not able to see the pump curve for the pump I want so I was unsure.

Comment: Please accept the answer (that I just posted) so the question can be marked closed.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a diaphragm pump is a constant volume pump that can raise the pressure of the fluid as it is discharged from the pump, as shown in it's pump curve. You can try to find a pump that outputs the needed pressure, or have equipment after the pump to adjust the fluid's pressure.